# Why do I get "The 'img' attribute has no file associated with it." error in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

So I have this simple Django application where users can post diary as well as images. Here, uploading image is optional, so I have left the field as not required. The problem is when I leave the ImageField empty. Saving the post w/o image works fine, but when I try to GET the post, I run into the error. First let me show you the code. 
 models.py

```
class Diary(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    # some other stuff here 
    img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="everyday_img")
```

forms.py

```
class DiaryInputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # some other stuff here.
    img = forms.ImageField(required=False)
```

views.py

```
def InputDiary(request):
    
    form = DiaryInputForm(initial={'authuser':request.user})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DiaryInputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.authuser = request.user
            # some other stuff here

            user_img = request.FILES.get('img', None)

            instance.save()
            return redirect('/diary/diarymain')

    return render(request,'diary/diaryinput.html', {'form':form})

def ViewDiary(request, authuser_id, slug):
    today = Diary.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'diary/diaryview.html', {'today' : today})
```

diaryview.html

```
...
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col col-12">
        <div class="detail-contents">
            <img src="{{today.img.url}}" class="user-img"><br>
            {{today.what|safe}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

So when `diaryview.html` is loaded, the error occurs. I know it's obviously because the `img` column has no data, but I have no idea on how I should deal with it. Thank you very much in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse the files too from the form

```
if request.FILES.get('img'):
    instance.img= request.FILES.get('img')
```

also make sure you have `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` defined in the `settings.py` file and also `url` in `urls.py` file to serve media and static files.

also do this in the html

```
<img src="{{today.img.url|default_if_none:'#' }}" class="user-img"><br>
```

Comment: Thank you. However posting with images works fine. The problem occurs when there isn't one. And the error persists even with your code :(

Comment: Should there be some default setting for cases w/o images?

Comment: just try this one last time @RyanOh